# R: What's the easiest way to print out pairs of values from a data.frame?

Tags: list, r, dataframe

I have a data.frame:

```
df<-data.frame(a=c("x","x","y","y"),b=c(1,2,3,4))

> df
      a b
    1 x 1
    2 x 2
    3 y 3
    4 y 4
```

What's the easiest way to print out each pair of values as a list of strings like this:

> "x1", "x2", "y1", "y2"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
apply(df, 1, paste, collapse="")
```

Answer (score 5):

```
with(df, paste(a, b, sep=""))
```

And this should be faster than `apply`.

***About timing***

For 10000 rows we get:

```
df <- data.frame(
    a = sample(c("x","y"), 10000, replace=TRUE),
    b = sample(1L:4L, 10000, replace=TRUE)
)

N = 100
mean(replicate(N, system.time( with(df, paste(a, b, sep="")) )["elapsed"]), trim=0.05)
# 0.005778
mean(replicate(N, system.time( apply(df, 1, paste, collapse="") )["elapsed"]), trim=0.05)
# 0.09611
```

So increase in speed is visible for few thousands.
It's because Shane's solution call `paste` for each row separately. So there is `nrow(df)` calls of `paste`, in my solution is one call.

Comment: I doubt the speed will be noticeably different unless you have millons of rows.

Comment: @hadley My solution is vectorized, what implies better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use `sqldf` library:

```
library("sqldf")
df<-data.frame(a=c("x","x","y","y"),b=c(1,2,3,4))
result <- sqldf("SELECT a || cast(cast(b as integer) as text) as concat FROM df")
```

You will get the following result:

```
  concat
1 x1
2 x2
3 y3
4 y4
```